# Access an sdtClass object with PHP

Tags: php

I have a request like that.

I have this function

```
 public function getBalances(string $id) : ?\stdClass
    {
        try {
            $recipientbalances = $this->pagarme->recipients()->getBalance([
                'recipient_id' => $id,
            ]);

            $this->recipientBalance = $recipientbalances;
            return $recipientbalances;
            
        } catch (PagarMeException $ex) {
            $this->error = $ex->getMessage();
            return null;
        }
    }

$balances = $integration->getBalances('re_ckyxi43rghnk9tc51zxg0b');
```

with var_dump($balances);

I have return:

```
object(stdClass)[70]
  public 'object' => string 'balance' (length=7)
  public 'waiting_funds' => 
    object(stdClass)[67]
      public 'amount' => int 185160
  public 'transferred' => 
    object(stdClass)[48]
      public 'amount' => int 0
  public 'available' => 
    object(stdClass)[66]
      public 'amount' => int 0
```

I can't access for example just the amount.

I tried like this by looping with foreach

```
foreach ($balances as $balance):            
              
  echo $balance->amount;
  
endforeach;
```

I tried like this with var_dump:

```
var_dump($balances->amount)

var_dump ($ balances ['amount'])
```

And nothing's right, can someone help me. I thank you in advance;

Comment: Which `amount` do you want to access? There doesn't seem to be any `amount` field on that object, but there are `waiting_funds`, `transferred` and `available` fields each having an `amount` field.

Comment: the amount that is within public 'waiting_funds' =>, see public 'waiting_funds' => 
    object(stdClass)[67]
      public 'amount' => int 185160

Comment: Look at the indentation of that output. The `stdClass` instance has the following fields: `object`, `waiting_funds`, `transferred` and `available`. `object` is a `string` with the value `balance`. `waiting_funds` is an `stdClass` with a field `amount` which is an `int` with the value `185160`. Etc...

Comment: because that's exactly what I need to access but I'm not getting it.

Comment: If you want to access `object`, the syntax would be `$balance->object`. If you want to access `amount` from `waiting_funds`, the syntax would be `$balance->waiting_funds->amount`. If you want to access `amount` from `transferred`, the syntax would be `$balance->transferred->amount`. Etc...

Comment: I tried using this syntax, but got the error: "Trying to get property 'waiting_funds' of non-object in". I don't know why this error.

Comment: If `$balances` is the object, then use `$balances` instead of `$balance`.

Comment: Now it worked. I was trying to access it within a foreach loop, now it seems just echo and it worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: Now it worked. I was trying to access inside a foreach loop, so I was getting the error, I just tried echo $ balances-> waiting_funds-> amount and it worked, but I was in doubt if I have more than one object, a foreach would fail or just failed because it has only one result?

Comment: If `var_dump($balances)` shows an object, then it's not an array and it can't be looped over.